# Entity Framework navigational property between different column names

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, mapping

I have two EF models -

```
public class What
{
    [Key]
    public int primary_key_What { get; set; }
    public int another_column_What { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Why> Whys { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class Why
{
    [Key]
    public int primary_key_Why { get; set; }
    public int some_column_Why { get; set; }

    public virtual What What { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, I have to use **another_column_What** and **some_column_Why** for navigating between the two. As you can see none of them are keys or declared unique in the database, also their names are different.

I've tried all the ways I could imagine of and found on search, but none of them works. How and in which model mapping do I use to say, navigate between What and Why using **another_column_What** and **some_column_Why** columns.

So whenever a query is generated by EF, it will compare **another_column_What** with **some_column_Why**?

Very unfortunately, changing the database architecture (or even column names) is not an option here.

Can anyone please help me with it?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1o2yyNs1II&list=PLIoX3-mcY80gLduhSJcrH0wAefC6gyS_C&index=2 Try to watch this.

Comment: This is not an FK relationship, so I think you'll have to join in-memory.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro, could you please explain what you meant by in-memory?

Comment: Load your What and Why into memory using .ToList() and then fill your navigation properties with linq queries on those lists. I don't think EF can do the join for you since it should only support regular (FK) relationships, so you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: Alright, got it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

Db schema:

[image]

What model:

```
[Table("what")]
public class what
{
    [Key]
    [Column("primary_key_what")]
    public int primary_key_what { get; set; }
    [Column("another_column_what")]
    public int another_column_what { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<why> whys { get; set; }
}
```

Why model:

```
[Table("why")]
public class why
{
    [Key]
    [Column("primary_key_why")]
    public int primary_key_why { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("what")]
    [Column("some_column_why")]
    public int some_column_why { get; set; }
    public virtual what what { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<what> what { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<why> why { get; set; }
    public Context() : base("name=SqlConnection")
    {
    }
}
```

Main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var context = new Context())
    {
        var results = from w in context.what
                      select w;

        foreach (var what in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("what.primary_key_what = {0}", what.primary_key_what);
            Console.WriteLine("what.another_column_what = {0}", what.another_column_what);
            Console.WriteLine("what has {0} whys", what.whys.Count);
            foreach (var why in what.whys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Why.primary_key_why = {0}", why.primary_key_why);
                Console.WriteLine("Why.some_column_why = {0}", why.some_column_why);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What data:

[image]

Why data:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer man. I tried your solution, but "Why" actually tries to match with the primary key of "What". You can easily see it if you change the values of the table, or change the column data-types. Do we have any other options?